# To fix error ; make fit for big 40 data ,Add x asis value at buttom ,Reduce bar width and space between bar and label

Tags: tikz-pgf

[image]

I want to fit big data inside it but it get blur when data increases .Blur appear downward . Also guide me how to reduce the width of the bar .i have more than 50 data .Fit in a way such that 50 item comes in a page.Thanks

Here is the code:
I want to fix code to fit for 50 data:
need another code for 27  item

```
\documentclass{article}  
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}  
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % \filldraw[black!10](-1,2) rectangle (32,-32);
        % \node at (8,1.5) (b) {\bfseries \large Data Visualization  \color{blue}{2022} and \color{red}{2021}};
        % \node at (8,1) (b) {\bfseries (in number)};
        \foreach \i/\t/\d/\dr in {
        1/Unzureichende Minimalisierung /21/3.5,
        2/Unzureichende automatisierte Auswertung von Protokolldaten/14/3.6,
        3/Administration ohne personenbezogene Konten/10/3,
        4/Leeres Template/9/2,
        5/Schwächen im Firewallregelwerk/9/2,
        6/Unzureichende Prüfung der Datensicherungsprozesse/2.5/2,
        7/Fourth  /2.5/2,
        8/Fourth  /2.5/2,
        9/Fourth  /2.5/2,
        17/Fourth  /2.5/2,
        18/Fourth  /2.5/2}{%
           \pgfmathsetmacro{\j}{100-10*\i};
            \node[anchor=west,violet] at (.1,{-2*(\i-1)+.2}) (a\i) {\bfseries  \t};
            \filldraw[blue!\j] (0,{-.5-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\d,{-2*(\i-1)}) node[pos=.5,white] () {\bfseries \d};
            \filldraw[red!\j] (0,{-1.2-2*(\i-1)}) rectangle (\dr,{-.7-2*(\i-1)}) node[pos=.5,white] () {\bfseries \dr};
        }
        \node[violet,rotate=90] at (-.5,-3) () {\Large \bfseries Events};
        \node[violet] at (4,-20.8) () {\Large \bfseries Quantity};
    \end{tikzpicture}  
\end{document}
```

Here is my data :
21  Unzureichende Minimalisierung
14  Unzureichende automatisierte Auswertung von Protokolldaten
10  Administration ohne personenbezogene Konten
9   Leeres Template
9   Schwächen im Firewallregelwerk
8   Unzureichende Prüfung der Datensicherungsprozesse
7   Unzureichende Umsetzung des Management-Netzwerkes
6   Fehlende Rollentrennung bei Datenbankkonten
6   Mangelhafte sudo-Konfiguration
5   Fehlende Mikrosegmentierung

5   Lückenhafdministration ohne personenbezogene Kontente Dokumentation des Firewallregelwerks
5   Lückenhafte Härtung der Secure Shell
5   Lückenhaftes Patchmanagement
5   Unzureichende Protokolldaten
5   Unzureichende Protokollierungsarchitektur
4   Fehlende Verschlüsselung der Datensicherung
3   Unsichere Speicherung von Passwörtern
3   Unzureichende Netzsegmentierung
3   Veraltete Firmware
2   Fehlende dedizierte Administrationsrechner
2   Kurze Verfügbarkeit von Datensicherungen
2   Nutzung unsicher entwickelter Software
2   Unsichere Speicherung von sensiblen Informationen
2   Unvollständiges Sicherheitskonzept
2   Unzureichende Trennung unterschiedlicher Anwendungsumgebungen
2   Verwendung von Trivialpasswörtern
1   Administration mit unsicheren Werkzeugen
1   Fehlende Firewall-Leitlinie
1   Fehlerhafter HTTP Header [quote]Content-Security-Policy[/quote]
1   Lückenhafte Dokumentation
1   Lückenhafte Umsetzung des Sicherheitskonzepts
1   Mangelhaftes Krypto-Schlüsselmanagement
1   Mangelhafte Web-Proxy-Konfiguration
1   Ressourcenmangel
1   Unklare Aufteilung der Verantwortlichkeiten
1   Unsichere Transportverschlüsselung der Datenbank
1   Unzureichend eingeschränkte administrative Schnittstellen
1   Unzureichendes Virenschutzkonzept
1   Unzureichende virtuelle Netzsegmentierung
1   Verbesserungswürdige NFS-Konfiguration
1   Wiederverwendung von Passwörtern

Comment: If you have more than 10 items, don't use `100-10*\i` but for example `100-3*\i`, or `max(100-10*\i,50)` so that it doesn't get under `50`.

Comment: Thanks ,Its working .And one more thing how can i reduce the width of bart

Comment: Also how can i move the bar cart to top left cornor .I means to full page

Comment: Also how to decrease space between bars

Comment: Space between bar and label